# JQuery string printout disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JQuery. 
Trying to create a blog page. When user enters name, country and comment, i want to print it out underneath the HTML form.

The script i'm using is as follows:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".addButton").click(function() {
            var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
            var country = $("select[name=countries]").val();
            var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();
            $(".comments").append("<div class='new-comment'>" + name + " (" + country + "):</br>" + comment + "</div>");                
        });
    });
```

This prints out my variables but only for a fracture of a second and they disappear. Any explanation would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the HTML? It's possible that `.addButton` is a `<button>` element with unspecified type and is causing the page to postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<button>` tags will submit the form, causing the page to reload. Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the form submission.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var country = $("select[name=countries]").val();
    var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();
    $(".comments").append("<div class='new-comment'>" + name + " (" + country + "):</br>" + comment + "</div>");
  });
});
```